# ffmpeg mysteriously not recording audio in a video

Tags: ffmpeg

I recently upgraded my MacBook Early 2015 2.9 i5 8gb ram computer to BigSur 11.3.1.
My previous command that would record a video with audio no longer works. The video is recording, but there is no audio. Here is the output. Does anybody have any thoughts on what may be the cause of this or how to troubleshoot. I've been trying different solutions all day! Here is the output when I run the command and hit control-C to stop recording:

`ffmpeg -y -thread_queue_size 512 -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -async 1 -i "1" -thread_queue_size 512 -f avfoundation -framerate 30 -video_size 640x480 -i "0":"0" -c:v libopenh264  -crf 30 -preset ultrafast -filter_complex "[0]scale=iw/16:ih/16 [pip]; [1][pip] overlay=main_w-overlay_w-10:main_h-overlay_h-10" -r 30 -movflags +faststart "/Users/research/Desktop/1_1_MorGen_May-18th-2021-1-47-08-pm.mp4"`

```
ffmpeg version N-102535-g6ff2aba088-tessus  https://evermeet.cx/ffmpeg/  Copyright (c) 2000-2021 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple clang version 11.0.0 (clang-1100.0.33.17)
  configuration: --cc=/usr/bin/clang --prefix=/opt/ffmpeg --extra-version=tessus --enable-avisynth --enable-fontconfig --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libdav1d --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgsm --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libmysofa --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenh264 --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvmaf --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-libzimg --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-version3 --pkg-config-flags=--static --disable-ffplay
  libavutil      57.  0.100 / 57.  0.100
  libavcodec     59.  1.100 / 59.  1.100
  libavformat    59.  2.100 / 59.  2.100
  libavdevice    59.  0.100 / 59.  0.100
  libavfilter     8.  0.101 /  8.  0.101
  libswscale      6.  0.100 /  6.  0.100
  libswresample   4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
  libpostproc    56.  0.100 / 56.  0.100
[AVFoundation indev @ 0x7f8ef8f04ac0] Configuration of video device failed, falling back to default.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8f04640] Stream #0: not enough frames to estimate rate; consider increasing probesize
Input #0, avfoundation, from '1':
  Duration: N/A, start: 7316.562000, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 2560x1600, 1000k tbr, 1000k tbn
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580] Selected pixel format (yuv420p) is not supported by the input device.
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580] Supported pixel formats:
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580]   uyvy422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580]   yuyv422
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580]   nv12
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580]   0rgb
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580]   bgr0
[avfoundation @ 0x7f8ef8c11580] Overriding selected pixel format to use uyvy422 instead.
Input #1, avfoundation, from '0:0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 7317.372133, bitrate: N/A
  Stream #1:0: Video: rawvideo (UYVY / 0x59565955), uyvy422, 640x480, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn
  Stream #1:1: Audio: pcm_f32le, 48000 Hz, stereo, flt, 3072 kb/s
Codec AVOption crf (Select the quality for constant quality mode) specified for output file #0 (/Users/research/Desktop/1_1_MorGen_May-18th-2021-1-47-08-pm.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Codec AVOption preset (Configuration preset) specified for output file #0 (/Users/research/Desktop/1_1_MorGen_May-18th-2021-1-47-08-pm.mp4) has not been used for any stream. The most likely reason is either wrong type (e.g. a video option with no video streams) or that it is a private option of some encoder which was not actually used for any stream.
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 (rawvideo) -> scale (graph 0)
  Stream #1:0 (rawvideo) -> overlay:main (graph 0)
  overlay (graph 0) -> Stream #0:0 (libopenh264)
  Stream #1:1 -> #0:1 (pcm_f32le (native) -> aac (native))
Press [q] to stop, [?] for help
[libopenh264 @ 0x7f8ef8e63880] Slice count will be set automatically
[libopenh264 @ 0x7f8ef8e63880] [OpenH264] this = 0x0x7f8ef8f16110, Warning:SliceArgumentValidationFixedSliceMode(), unsupported setting with Resolution and uiSliceNum combination under RC on! So uiSliceNum is changed to 6!
[libopenh264 @ 0x7f8ef8e63880] [OpenH264] this = 0x0x7f8ef8f16110, Warning:bEnableFrameSkip = 0,bitrate can't be controlled for RC_QUALITY_MODE,RC_BITRATE_MODE and RC_TIMESTAMP_MODE without enabling skip frame.
-async is forwarded to lavfi similarly to -af aresample=async=1:min_hard_comp=0.100000:first_pts=0.
Output #0, mp4, to '/Users/research/Desktop/1_1_MorGen_May-18th-2021-1-47-08-pm.mp4':
  Metadata:
    encoder         : Lavf59.2.100
  Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, progressive), 640x480, q=2-31, 30 fps, 15360 tbn (default)
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.100 libopenh264
    Side data:
      cpb: bitrate max/min/avg: 0/0/2000000 buffer size: 0 vbv_delay: N/A
  Stream #0:1: Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 128 kb/s
    Metadata:
      encoder         : Lavc59.1.100 aac
[mp4 @ 0x7f8ef8e0e300] Starting second pass: moving the moov atom to the beginning of the file speed=1.12x    
frame=   62 fps= 32 q=-0.0 Lsize=     464kB time=00:00:02.06 bitrate=1836.1kbits/s dup=10 drop=0 speed=1.06x    
video:460kB audio:1kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: 0.671077%
[aac @ 0x7f8ef8e64800] Qavg: 65536.000
Exiting normally, received signal 2.
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out; I hope my solution will help others.

For some reason ZoomAudioDevice the '0' slot in my devices. Why in the world wouldn't that be reserved for the Built-in Microphone, ALWAYS? To make matters works, the ZoomAudioDevice was not in the Settings Panel in BigSur, so it couldn't be removed manually. I had to Uninstall Zoom, then do a command-alt-P-R (20 second) reboot to free it up. Now Zoom is gone, avfoundation has only one audio input (0 = built in microphone) and everything is working as before. I guess the lesson is 'Beware of Zoom'?